# Why does typeof function return "function"?

Tags: javascript, object, types, typeof

If both array and function are object subtypes, then why does `typeof function` return `"function"` and `typeof array` return `"object"`?

Comment: Please show a full code sample.

Comment: @Ryan Which full code would be needed here?

Comment: ***Because.*** I really don't think you're going to get a better answer than that. When defining `typeof` all those years ago, Brendan Eich decided that functions should be differentiated from other objects, but that most other objects shouldn't be differentiated from each other. Function objects do have a fundamental difference compared to other objects: They're callable.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: `typeof` doesn’t return the constructor of an object, if that’s what you’re asking. It’s for a few specific type checks. Compare how `(function () {}).constructor` is `Function` and `[].constructor` is `Array`, and `(function () {}) instanceof Object`.

Comment: @Ryan I know, my question was about why it returned different strings for function and arrays

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) defines different behaviour for `typeof` when it interacts with objects *implementing `[[Call]]`* (i.e. functions).

Answer (score 4):

Very ugly, yet correct answer: because ECMAScript specification says so.
Keep in mind that on the low level, every array is basically a mere object with "length" property.

If you want to check if given object is actually an array, use [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).