# Why are a lot of Standard built-in objects called objects when they are actually functions?

Tags: javascript

[Here is the list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects) on MDN. Some Standard built-in objects are actually objects like

```
typeof WebAssembly // "object"
```

but others are functions

```
typeof Array // "function"
typeof Number // "function"
```

Comment: so what answer you want?

Comment: Because they are "constructors"?

Comment: WebAssembly is an instance, and Array & Numbers are not.

Comment: [Why does typeof function return "function"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467581/why-does-typeof-function-return-function#42467620) - if it is an _object (native and does not implement [[Call]])_, then `typeof` returns "object".

Answer (score 0):

In JS everything is an object. Including functions and arrays.

For example, you can do this:

```js
function foo() {}
foo.bar = 123
console.log(foo.bar) // 123
```

Primitives (string, number, boolean, undefined, null, symbol) are *kinda* objects:

```js
let foo = 'bar'
console.log(foo.length) // 3
foo.length = 5
console.log(foo.length) // 3, because mutation of primitive objects is prohibited
```

Regarding, why `Array`, `Number` are functions, not just *plain objects*.
Because they are used as constructors as well (unlike WebAssembly):

```
let arr = Array(1,2,3) // [1,2,3]
let num = Number('123') // 123
```