# Global Object is a Global Variable?

Tags: javascript

MDN Says:

> A global variable, window, representing the window in which the script is running, is exposed to JavaScript

this is very confusing because window is a global variable. How is window a global variable and a global object?

Comment: I'm not sure the term `global object` really means anything. Names have scope, not objects.

Comment: Every variable that is not `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `undefined` or `null` (`function`s are objects too, but `typeof ()=>{}` returns `'function'` [answer why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42467620/8820629)) (which `window` is not) is an object.

Comment: because the value of `window` *is* an object (and not an array, string, number or boolean)

Comment: @Lux arrays are object too.

Comment: "Global variables are actually properties of  a single global object, which in browsers is called window" - Mr. Guil from TeamTreeHouse. One more thing what is the global environment? is it the global scope? the same teacher says that alert() & location.href are part of many more variables in the global environment

Comment: @SkillGG whats stored in the variable right because a variable itself is not an object according to what i have learned

Comment: @HeavensGate666 yes. Should have written `that does not store [...] stores an object`. That's right. Cannot edit it anymore though.

Comment: @SkillGG what do you think of this -> "Global variables are actually properties of a single global object, which in browsers is called window" - Mr. Guil from TeamTreeHouse. One more thing what is the global environment? is it the global scope? the same teacher says that alert() & location.href are part of many more variables in the global environment

Answer (score 1):

Object would be the type of `window`.

So `window` is a global variable that is an object.

Answer (score 0):

"A global object is an object that always exists in the global scope.

In JavaScript, there's always a global object defined. In a web browser, when scripts create global variables, they're created as members of the global object. (In Node.js this is not the case.) The global object's interface depends on the execution context in which the script is running. For example:

In a web browser, any code which the script doesn't specifically start up as a background task has a Window as its global object. This is the vast majority of JavaScript code on the Web.
Code running in a Worker has a WorkerGlobalScope object as its global object.
Scripts running under Node.js have an object called global as their global object." - MDN ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object )

"A global variable is a  variable that is declared in the global scope in other words, a variable that is visible from all other scopes.

In JavaScript it is a property of the global object." - MDN 
 ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_variable )